# How to evaluate all possible groups of adjacent tiles in 2D array?

Tags: javascript, permutation

I'm working on a tile based game idea in Javascript. It's a math puzzle game where players move around tiles with numbers on them, and the goal is to connect groups of tiles that have a sum of certain goal number, for example 5 or 7 or 9.
[image]
However, I'm stuck on the algorithm to detect these sum groups. I know how to do a [flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm using recursion to detect a group of adjacent tiles, like in the [same game](https://www.google.com/search?q=same+game&oq=same&tbm=isch). But I don't know how to iterate through all the possible permutations of possible groups, and what is the best way to approach this?

Because the problem is that adjacent tiles form a group, but within that group of tiles there are many possibilities for sub groups. See tiles example below

```
Tile letters     Contains numbers
+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+
| A | B | C |    | 1 | 5 | 2 |
+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+
| D | E | . |    | 2 | 1 | . |
+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+
| F | . | . |    | 4 | . | . |
+---+---+---+    +---+---+---+
```

So the group is all the tiles A though F, and a subgroup could be A, B and E (1+5+1) but also A, D and F (1+2+4). But A, C and F is not a possible group because those tiles are not adjacent.

How to systematically go through and evaluate all possible permutations? Is there an algorithm for something like this? Or can some one explain how to approach this problem?

Comment: A floodfill with backtracking sounds like a good idea. My quick guess would be that this is an algorithmically hard problem, where brute force enumeration is the only solution, but that it shouldn't matter for small game boards. Start the floodfill on the newly inserted tile

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58207737/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/115405/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).